# "May very well have" or "very well may have": Which is correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I was having a discussion with some friends recently. Some were insistent that the phrase is "very well may have", e.g.

> I very well may have taken your jacket.

Whereas others were saying that it's "may very well have", e.g.

> I may very well have taken your jacket.

Is one grammatically incorrect? Or are they both equally usable?

Comment: Either one's correct. _Very well_ is just to emphasize the likelihood, and it can go before either auxiliary verb (_may_ or _have_).

Comment: You missed out [***I may have very well***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+may+have+very+well%2CI+may+very+well+have%2CI+very+well+may+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) - admittedly less common than your two, but common enough to show on that linked chart. I must admit I find it odd that I can hesitantly say *I **may very well** have done it* and emphatically *I **jolly well** did it!*, but I can't emphatically say *I **very well** did it!*

Answer (score 1):

The second choice feels unusual; the following ngram confirms that it is not frequently used.

[image]

The use of the emphasizer "well" without the intensifier "very" makes this position of the adverbial even more undesirable.

[image]

- I may very well have taken your jacket.

The ngram for all verbs shows that the adverbial is rarely placed right after the subject.

[image]

Comment: I must admit the third permutation *(**I may have very well taken it**)* sounds at least a *bit* "odd" to me - but even that version (just about) works for me with, say, ***I may have very well said that***. I certainly have no problem with either of OP's offerings, even though I know one's much more *likely* than the other.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The ngram seems to confirm the uneasiness felt: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=may+have+very+well%2Cmay+very+well+have&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3